# Can I make TypeScript better understand this generator in a union?

Tags: typescript, generator, yield, union-types

In this example:

```js
type Union = () => Generator<undefined, void, number> | void;

function callbacker(_callback: Union) {}

callbacker(function* () {
    const value = yield;
});
```

TypeScript errors with: `'yield' expression implicitly results in an 'any' type because its containing generator lacks a return-type annotation.`

If I remove the `void` from the union it works, but I really need void in there.

Is there any way to make it work without touching the call to `callbacker`? This is part of a library and I want that the user to have automatic inference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function overloading like this:

```js
type Union = () => Generator<undefined, void, number> | void;

function callbacker(_callback: () => Generator<undefined, void, number>): void;
function callbacker(_callback: () => void): void;
function callbacker(_callback: Union) {}

callbacker(function* () {
    const value = yield;
});
```